# Ruby models, should I choose Inheritance or just associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following tables and fields

```
 User   :username,:password,:email

 Organiser  :organiser_specific_fields

 Participant  :participant_specific_fields
```

Orgnaisers and Participants are Users,

Users already exist in system,

When a User organises a Party, I create an instance of Party class, add him as Organiser of that Party and add other Users as Participants.

How do I model this in Rails? I couldn't figure out what's the best way to implement this  in Rails considering that Users already exist in the system.

Comment: Are the organiser and participant specific fields related to a given party? (e.g. like "participates (yes/no)", "brings muffins", "makes the barbecue sauce")

Comment: Yes they are, also Users who is an Organiser of one Party can be a Participant of another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you comments I suggest that you stick with the following schema:

1. A user table, saving all the details about a user (firstname, lastname)
2. A party table with all the details about a party (time, location, ...)
3. Two join tables for the models outlined below:

---

This code is untested, it might need some tweaking of the names:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parties, :through => :participations, :source => :user
    has_many :organised, :through => :organises, :source => :user
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participants, :through => :participations
    has_many :organizers, :through => :organises
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :party
   # this class represents "a user is going to a party"
   # additional fields, which are specific to a participation go here as well
end

class Organises < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :party
    # This class represents "user is the organisator of a party"
    # additional fields, which are specific to organizing a party go here
end
```

Pros:

- You don't need to touch your user tables
- A party can have two or more organisators
- The party's organisators can go to the party as well (hopefully)
- No data duplication in your database

Cons:

- You have to manange the associations yourself: A user must not go to (or be the organisator) of the same party twice

I hope that helps to clear things up a bit. More info can be found in the rails docs at this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

depends on how many specific fields each of these are and how bad your user table would look with those additional fields. if Organiser and Participant are not seperate entities in the database, may be they could just be mixins!

But generally speaking, definitely inheritance IMHO.

Comment: They would have 2 specific fields for Organiser and Participant. If I need to use STInheritance can you link me to a good page to learn about it :-)

Comment: the [rails doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) is pretty alright. just do a find for 'Single table inheritance'.. HTH!